# How to download streets from different address in OSMNX

Tags: list, osmnx

I would like to download different streets in osmnx, using a list but can't find the error in my code.

I have tried this way

```
name_list = ['Kuwait, United Arab Emirates','Guangzhou, China']

i=0
for file_path in name_list:
    print(i)
    CD = file_path
    filtro_vialidades = '["highway"~"trunk|motorwat|primary|secondary|tertiary|residential"]'
    GCD=ox.graph_from_address(CD, network_type= "drive",
                              custom_filter= filtro_vialidades)
    ox.save_graphml(GCD, f"{name_list[i]}.graphml", gephi= False)
    i+=1
```

And have received this error

> ```
> EmptyOverpassResponse: There are no data elements in the response JSON
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kuwait is a country not a city.  You can add appropriate error handling code:

```
import osmnx as ox
from osmnx._errors import EmptyOverpassResponse

name_list = ['Kuwait, United Arab Emirates','Guangzhou, China']

for i, file_path in enumerate(name_list):
    print(i)
    CD = file_path
    filtro_vialidades = '["highway"~"trunk|motorwat|primary|secondary|tertiary|residential"]'
    try:
        GCD=ox.graph_from_address(CD, network_type= "drive",
                                  custom_filter= filtro_vialidades)
        ox.save_graphml(GCD, f"{name_list[i]}.graphml", gephi= False)
    except EmptyOverpassResponse:
        print(f"no results: {file_path}")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it cannot find anything for one of your queries, probably because "Kuwait, United Arab Emirates" does not exist. These are two separate countries.